# Accepting multiple integers on a single line using Scanner

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

The user needs to enter a certain number of integers. Rather them enter an integer at a time, I want to make it so they can enter multiple integers on a single line, then I want those integers to be converted in an array. For example, if the user enters: `56 83 12 99` then I want an array to be created that is `{56, 83, 12, 99}`

In other languages like Python or Ruby I would use a `.split(" ")` method to achieve this. No such thing exist in Java to my knowledge. Any advice on how to accept user input and create an array based on that, all on a single line?

Comment: Sorry, but -1 for the "no such thing exists..." line. Come on now, how hard did you actually look? Ignorance isn't a sin as we're not all born with Java knowledge, but not making the effort to remove it is.

Comment: I think this is the kindest negative feedback I have ever received. +1

Comment: LOL, I have to retract my -1 based on your response. Priceless.

Comment: One solution is to use more than one Scanner. The first Scanner would obtain lines of text, the second (created and destroyed inside of the loop) would parse each line, extracting your numbers.

Comment: @JarrodRobertson:  I don't agree with the duplicate.  While the questions are *similar*, that question is dealing with a fundamentally different problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Allow me to congratulate you for your recent 160K. I guess you got your present in this post :)

Comment: @user1803551: thanks but nope. Comment votes don't count towards reputation. For more on this, please see [Help Section: Reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I didn't mean that you achieved the reputation threshold here, just that the OP's "priceless" comment was a nice present for the occasion :P

Answer (score 5):

Using the `Scanner.nextInt()` method would do the trick:

Input:

> 56 83 12 99

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] numbers = new int[4];
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            numbers[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

At @user1803551's request on how `Scanner.hasNext()` can achieve this:

```
import java.util.*;

class Example2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (sc.hasNextInt()) { // this loop breaks there is no more int input.
            numbers.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but you don't know the exact size of the array you'd be getting back from the user, and this code only supports four elements.

Comment: That depends on the requirements. Really.

Comment: @Makoto - you can use an Arraylist, and Scanner.hasNext to support arbitrary number of elements. (:

Comment: Can you show how you would use `Scanner.hasNext()` to achieve this?

Comment: Your code continually asks for input - the loop never ends unless you give it something which is not an integer. The original request was *"if the user enters: `56 83 12 99` then I want an array to be created that is `{56, 83, 12, 99}`"*. Sure, this is very close and the OP might be flexible, but still it's not quite that.

Comment: I'll be frank, I know the answer. The reason I asked to show the code is that comments like "do this and that" which seem trivial, but are not, eventually give the OP hours of frustration because they are stuck on some caveat.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Makoto does what you want using `Scanner#nextLine` and `String#split`. The answer by mauris uses `Scanner#nextInt` and works if you are willing to change your input requirement such that the last entry is not an integer. I would like to show how to get `Scanner#nextLine` to work with the exact input condition you gave. Albeit not as practical, it does have educational value.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Preparation
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter numbers:");

    // Get the input
    while (scanner.hasNextInt())
        numbers.add(scanner.nextInt());

    // Convert the list to an array and print it
    Integer[] input = numbers.toArray(new Integer[0]);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input));
}
```

When giving the input `10 11 12` upon first prompt, the program stores them (`Scanner` has a `private` buffer), but then keeps asking for more input. This might be confusing since we give 3 integers which loop through `hasNext` and expect that when the 4th call is made there will be no integer and the loop will break.

To understand it we need to look at the documentation:

> Both `hasNext` and `next` methods [and their primitive-type companion methods] *may block* waiting for further input. Whether a `hasNext` method blocks has no connection to whether or not its associated `next` method will block.

(emphasis mine) and `hasNextInt`

> Returns: `true` if and only if this scanner's next token is a valid int value

What happens is that we initialized `scanner` with an `InputStream`, which is a *continuous* stream of data. On the 4th call to `hasNextInt`, the scanner "*does not know*" if there is a next int or not because the stream is still open and data is expected to come. To conclude from the documentation, we can say that `hasNextInt`

> Returns `true` if this scanner's next token is a valid int value, returns `false` if it is not a valid int, and blocks if it does not know what the next token is.

So what we need to do is close the stream after we got the input:

```
// Get the input
numbers.add(scanner.nextInt());
System.in.close();
while (scanner.hasNextInt())
    numbers.add(scanner.nextInt());
```

This time we ask for the input, get all of it, close the stream to inform `scanner` that `hasNextInt` does not need to wait for more input, and store it through iteration. The only problem here is that we closed `System.in`, but if we don't need more input it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

`String#split` exists, but you have to do more work, since you're only getting strings back.

Once you've got the split, convert each element into an `int`, and place it into the desired array.

```
final String intLine = input.nextLine();
final String[] splitIntLine = intLine.split(" ");
final int[] arr = new int[splitIntLine.length];
for(int i = 0; i < splitIntLine.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitIntLine[i]);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));  // prints contents of your array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scan2= new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList l2=new ArrayList();
    

System.out.print("How many numbers do you want in your list: ");
int numbers=scan2.nextInt();
while(numbers!=0){
     int age=scan2.nextInt();
     l2.add(age);
     numbers-=1;
   }
System.println(l2);
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: As mentioned in the earlier comment number of input element is unknown to user. And your code takes array size as input from user.

Comment: I thought that's better than having a fixed array size.